# Spring one-to-many Object in Thymeleaf Tab

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, one-to-many

I am using Spring and Thymeleaf templates. What I am trying is, to show a customer's addresses within a Thymeleaf template (using Bootstrap tabs) in a many-to-one relation.

[image]

I can't get the addresses to show up or add new ones. Any help is appreciated!

customerAddressform.html (Thymeleaf)

```html
    <html>

    <head lang="en">

        <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> /*/-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(address)}">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Address Id</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr th:each="address : ${address}">
                    <td th:text="${address.id}" href="/customer/${customer.id}/address/${address.id}">Id</td>
                    <td><a th:text="${address.addressId}" th:href="${ '/customer/' + customer.id + '/address/' + address.id}">Address
                            Id</a></td>
                    <td>description</td>
                    <td>price</td>
                    <td><a>Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" href="#" class="btn-primary btn-sm btn-block btn-addrow" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#modalNewCustomerAddress">+</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="modalNewCustomerAddress" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="New Address"
                aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">New Address</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body margin-15">
                            <form id="customerAddressForm" th:object="${address}" th:action="@{/customer/{customer.id}/address/new}" method="post">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <input type="hidden" />
                                    <input type="hidden" />
                                        <label for="streetName">Street:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" th:field="*{streetName}" id="streetName" />

                                        <label for="houseNumber">House Number:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="houseNumber"/>

                                        <label for="postalCode">Postal Code:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="postalCode"/>

                                        <label for="city">City:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="city"/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" form="customerAddressForm" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

AddressController.java

```java
    @Controller
    public class AddressController {

        private AddressService addressService;

        @Autowired
        public void setAddressService(AddressService addressService) {
            this.addressService = addressService;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/address", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String list(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("address", addressService.listAllAddress());
            System.out.println("Returning address:");
            return "customerAddress";
        }

        // @RequestMapping("address/{id}")
        // public String showAddress(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model){
        //     model.addAttribute("address", addressService.getAddressById(id));
        //     return "addressshow";
        // }

        @RequestMapping("customer/{customer.id}/address")
        public String edit(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model){
            model.addAttribute("address", addressService.getAddressById(id));
            return "customerAddressform";
        }

        @RequestMapping("customer/{customer.id}/address/new")
        public String newAddress(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("address", new Address());
            return "customerAddressform";
        }

        // @RequestMapping(value = "address", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        // public String saveAddress(Address address){

        //     addressService.saveAddress(address);

        //     //return "redirect:/addresss";
        //     return "redirect:/address/" + address.getId();
        // }

        @RequestMapping("customer/{customer.id}/deleteAddress")
        public String deleteAddress(@RequestParam Integer id) {
            addressService.deleteAddressById(id);
            return "redirect:/customer/{customer.id}/address";
        }

    }
```

Address.java

```java
    @Entity
    public class Address {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        @Version
        private Integer version;

        private String addressId;
        private String addressType;
        private String streetName;
        private String houseNumber;
        private String postalCode;
        private String cityName;
        private String country;
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)

        private Customer customer;

        public Address(){

        }

        public Address(String addressId, String addressType, String streetName, String houseNumber, String postalCode, String cityName, String country, Customer customer){
            this.addressId = addressId;
            this.addressType = addressType;
            this.streetName = streetName;
            this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
            this.postalCode = postalCode;
            this.cityName = cityName;
            this.country = country;
            this.customer = customer;
        }
```

Customer.java

```java
    @Entity
    public class Customer {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        @Version
        private Integer version;

        private String customerId;
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="customer")
        private Set<Address> address;
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question, but one thing that is surely wrong is `@RequestMapping("customer/{customer.id}/address")`, should be `@RequestMapping("customer/{id}/address")` (The part inside `{}` should match with the name of your `@PathVariable` name)

Comment: I changed the Mapping. The Problem is, that the page does not show within the tab. The console gives the following error: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "ObjectTabs/customerAddressform" - line 52, col 109)] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'address' available as request attribute

I figured, that th:field="*{streetName}" is not available. I use th:object="${address}" th:action="@{/customer/{id}/address}" as the form attributes